# Не получается запланировать перезагрузку Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012

Дело в том, что перезагрузку я могу запланировать и это сделал как раз таки по вот этому гайду https://internet-lab.ru/windows_server_reboot_scheduler
но проблема в том, что сервер выключается, но обратно почему-то не включается. Вы скажете, что как можно отдать команду выключенной машине. А я вам скажу, я поставил галочку Run whether user is logged on or not и ещё Run with highest privileges. После чего ввёл данные от сервера. Там есть мои данные для входа, почему оно не может включить его???

Comment: и да, параметр /r у меня выставлен

Comment: Ну а в журналах чё-нить есть по этому поводу?